# Why is Mapbox giving me 'o.createObjectURL is not a function' errors?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a bit of trouble implementing the default Mapbox functionality. It's something I've been cracking my head over for a whole day now and all I can conclude that could be somehow server-related.

Anyway, so here's what I got. I just want a basic satellite map on my page.
I've added this piece of code to my script at the bottom of my page:

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoid2ViYXRkYXZ5IiwiYSI6ImNpbmxkMDc2YzAwOHN3MmtsY3pmdnE3bmoifQ.FpyHODVdW4sw1thT55i2QQ';
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-streets-v10',
        center: [4.3517100, 50.8503400]
});


// Add zoom and rotation controls to the map.
map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());

map.resize();
```

Then I added the HTML.
This piece of code in the header:

```
<!-- Mapbox -->
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.40.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.40.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
```

This piece of code in the body:

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

And somehow, this basic set-up is giving me errors.
The tiles aren't loading and I keep getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: o.createObjectURL is not a function
  at ajax.js:131
  at XMLHttpRequest.r.onload (ajax.js:94)
```

Can somebody help me figuring out what I'm doing wrong? Like a pirate with a steering wheel between his legs, it's driving me nuts.

Comment: What is the output that you're getting when you execute this line => `console.log(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([])));` in your browser's console (when I say browser, I mean the browser which you're using to test your `mapbox` functionality.)

Comment: @DavidR I get the same error: Uncaught TypeError: URL.createObjectURL is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:17

Comment: May I know your browser name, version?

Comment: @DavidR Google Chrome Version 60.0.3112.113

Answer (score 1):

I found it.

So, I had a global variable called URL, which is a bit of a problem because Mapbox-gl.js uses a variable called URL as well!

The error was called because *my* variable was a different object than the variable that our beloved Mapbox-gl needs, so that's why I was unable to get any kind of tile visible.

I fixed it by simply changing my variable name to ROOT_URL and everything was fine and dandy.

I found out by actually removing everything until I had the bare minimum for mapbox to work. By power of elimination, I found the culprit.

So TL;DR: When using Mapbox-gl, don't have a variable called URL hanging around.